# MS Word Interop: Group image and label

Tags: c#, .net, interop, shapes, word-interop

I am trying to group the image and text in one shape using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in C# .NET Framework 4.7 application.
At the moment of grouping I have strange error "Grouping is desactivated for selected shapes"

Code:

```
    public static void TestWordImageGrouping(string documentPath)
    {
        _Document doc = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        try
        {

            #region Document setup

            app.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;
            object template = Missing.Value;
            object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
            object documentType = Missing.Value;
            object visible = Missing.Value;

            doc = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);

            //New version
            doc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA3;
            doc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
            doc.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595.276F * 2;
            doc.PageSetup.PageHeight = 841.8898F;
            doc.PageSetup.TopMargin = 20;
            doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0;
            doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0;
            doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0;
            #endregion
            try
            {
                RectangleF imagePosition = new RectangleF(40, 30, 400, 320);
                RectangleF labelPosition = new RectangleF(40, 400, 400, 50);

                string imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content","fail.jpg");
                
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape imageShape = doc.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath, Left: imagePosition.X,
                    Top: imagePosition.Y, Width: imagePosition.Width, Height: imagePosition.Height);
                imageShape.Name = "Image1";


                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape imageLabel = doc.Shapes.AddLabel(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
                    labelPosition.X,
                    labelPosition.Y,
                    labelPosition.Width,
                    labelPosition.Height);

                imageLabel.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "It Expectance vs Real life";
                imageLabel.Name = "Label1";
                imageLabel.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                doc.SaveAs(FileName: documentPath);

                object shapesIndex = new object[] { imageShape.Name, imageLabel.Name };
                var range = doc.Shapes.Range(shapesIndex);
                doc.Save();
                range.Group();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            app.Visible = true;
            app.Activate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ex.ToString());
            try
            {
                doc.Saved = true;
                app.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception exept)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(exept.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Same time, i succeed to group three designed in code lines.
Can you, please, share the solution if you successfully resolved problem like this with C# .Net Framework Word interop

Thank you.